# Typescript in VSCode not showing error concatenating string with number

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Typescript, and while trying a very simple script I cannot see the linter (neither the compiler) erroring out the following:

No error detected:

```typescript
let a: string = 'hello';
let b: number = 10;

a += b;

console.log(a);
```

[image: 1]

I tried changing the tsconfig file and couldn't make it work. Any tips on where to look?

For references, this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2016",                                  

    "module": "commonjs",                                
    "rootDir": "./src",                                  

    "sourceMap": true,                                

    "outDir": "./dist",                                   
    "removeComments": true,                           

    "noEmitOnError": true,                            

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            

    "strict": true,                                      

    "alwaysStrict": true,                             

    "skipLibCheck": true,                                 

  },
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I've transcribed the image for you, since it's very short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not considered an error. TypeScript respects JavaScript's implicit value conversion with the various operators (`+`, `-`, etc.). From a type perspective doing `someString + someNumber` is valid, and results in a value of type `string`. The number is implicitly converted to string and then the strings are concatenated. Even the various [`strict` options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) will allow that implicit conversion.

Even strictly-typed languages like Java and C# allow implicitly converting numbers to strings when performing `+` operations.

Answer (score 1):

there is not an error, its valid in Ts. it will throw an error if type of a will be changed, but here type of `a` remains same as `string`

```
let a :string = "Hello";
let b :number = 10
```

you are doing `a += b;`
that is same as `a = a + b;`

but here type of `a` remains sting because `+` operator add numbers and strings as well.

so `a = "hello" + 10` will `a = hello10` that is string.

it will give error if you do

```
b += a;
```

because here type of b will changed to string that is not valid in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid JavaScript. When using the `+=` operator in combination with a `String`, JavaScript converts each value to a `String`. So you can see it like

```js
a = a + String(b)
a = 'Hello' + '10'
```

Therefore you do not change to type of `a`

Comment: Yes, but the question is about why it's valid *TypeScript* (e.g., why there isn't a compile-time static type error), as there would be if you had a function accepting a `string` parameter and called it passing in a number -- which is perfectly valid JavaScript, but [causes a TypeScript type error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGcAuRIqAJxjAHMBKRAbwChF3EIEi58A6XHFrF6AbhYBfFizRY8hACwAmMUA).

Comment: No, this is not a TypeScript error. The compiler is correct. I've [modified your example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGcAuRIqAJxjAHMBKRAbwChF3EIEi58A6XHFrF6AbhYBfFizRY8hAOQAJZLkELEAakQAWAExigA) to explain it

Comment: I'm afraid you missed my point. The point is that `string + number` is not a type error (it just results in `string`), and the question is asking about why it isn't a type error, not about JavaScript. The example I gave was to illustrate the fact that things that are not errors in JavaScript can be errors in TypeScript, it wasn't a reformulation of the OP's question. It was to underscore the difference between JavaScript and TypeScript, and why just saying "this is valid JavaScript" doesn't answer the question.